# Matlab: Do not use splines when plotting

Tags: matlab

If I generate a somewhat smooth curve:

```
t = 1:100;
x = sin(t/10);
```

[image]

Then Matlab uses splines to "connect the dots" and interpolate between my points. However, if the data is jagged enough, it seems that Matlab abandons this smoothing:

```
t = 1:100;
x = sin(t);
```

[image]

How can I manually tell the plot to use splines or straight lines to interpolate between points? In particular, I have the case where it is using splines, and I do not want that behavior.

Comment: As the answer says: MATLAB does not interpolate anything. Just makes lines. When you have enough points, your eyes (plus monitor) are not good enough to distinguish the lines. In a more scientific tone, aliasing is what you are experiencing, and Shannon had some things to say about sampling rates of periodic signals

Answer (score 3):

when you use MATLAB's plot function, it does not spline anything, it just simply connect each two points with a line